# Is there a way my program can detect if my microphone is being used by any programs? (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, arduino, microphone

**SHORT VERSION:**

I'm attempting to detect when my microphone is being captured by a program like Discord, preferably in Python, but I can't figure out how to do it. Any suggestions?

**LONG VERSION:**

I'm trying to write a program that will turn on an "On Air" light whenever my microphone is being used. Typically this would either be for Discord or Twitch. This is something Windows already monitors as well (Windows 10) because it displays a microphone icon down in the notifications tray and tells you what programs are using your microphone. Basically, whenever that icon notification is up, I want my light to be turned on.

The light is currently being run by sending serial commands through Python to an Arduino Nano, but I can only manually tell it to turn on or off.

I can't find a way to access windows privacy monitoring status or make any headway on just checking if a microphone is *in* use with Python. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can lock if the MicrophonIcon is displayed. Presice write an Pythonscript that locks if Pixel at the Position of the MicrophoneIcon having the Color off the MicrophonIcon. qt can do this. It has a python binding.

1. Get the Position of the MicrophonIcon( you can hover over it with the mouse and use a program to look the position up)
2. Get some Pixel Colors off the aria with qt
3. write a loop that checks if the Pixel Colors at the moment are equal to messured ones.

Con: if the Position off the Microphon changes(Screensize, other options that push it, not visable( fullscreen)) It will not work.

[image: Example Pixelspaxes]
If you checke the yello lines in 2 loops it should define the Microphone icon nearly failsafe if the position isnt changing

Comment: there is a good pythonlib for Mouse and Keycontroll but i for got the name

Comment: My hangups with that are:
1) It won't work if I do anything fullscreen
2) that color is used for the majority of icons in the notification tray, so I feel like false positives would be super common.

Comment: aganst the first point i cant do anithing. But the second isnt that problem it will make you more work, but you can take pixel next to the microphone that habe an over color

Comment: would it be an option to check if one of the programs is running? Windows has probably a commandline tool with that you can interackt if you use python subprocess

Comment: found some fing for that at https://www.nextofwindows.com/windows-tip-3-ways-to-print-a-list-of-running-processes  `tasklist > %userprofile%\desktop\processes.txt`